# Closed immersion of symmetric powers and retraction map.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

It is known that the symmetric power $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{A}^1)$ is the projective space $\mathbb{A}^n$. Consider the natural closed immersion $i^1_n:\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{A}^1)\hookrightarrow \text{Sym}^{n+1}(\mathbb{A}^1)$ induced by adding a point. This is equivalent to the closed immersion of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. This closed immersion has a retraction denoted by $r^1_{n+1}$, which is just the projection map. The retraction has the property $r_{n+1}^1\circ i_n=id$. Let's denote the same immersion corresponding to $i_n^1$ where $\mathbb{A}^1$ is replaced by $\mathbb{A}^m$ by $i_n^m$. Do the immersions $i_n^m$ admit algebraic/ homological (at the level of homology) retractions?

Comment: I think you may be a little confused. The projection map is only a rational map - it cannot be defined everywhere. (Indeed, if you take $\Bbb C$-points, your claim that it's a retraction would induce a homotopy equivalence between $\Bbb CP^n$ and $\Bbb CP^{n+1}$, which is impossible by looking at homology.)

Comment: @KReiser You are right it is a rational map. But then again I am talking about a retraction not a deformation retraction so I am not sure how it implies homotopy equivalence. But I think I should change it to some form of rational retraction.